# Retrofit2 shows onFailure but okhttp shows 200 ok

Tags: retrofit2, getmethod

I am having trouble displaying the data after using the GET method via retrofit2. It works on postman and okhttp logging but not on retrofit. Please advice.

OkHttp log:

```
2020-07-15 16:17:12.046 27072-27125/com.example.projjava I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> GET http://192.168.43.145/api/WorkSchedule/d7a8481f-02ae-458d-a220-71c4f5487540
2020-07-15 16:17:12.046 27072-27125/com.example.projjava I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: --> END GET
2020-07-15 16:17:12.547 27072-27125/com.example.projjava I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.43.145/api/WorkSchedule/d7a8481f-02ae-458d-a220-71c4f5487540 (499ms)
2020-07-15 16:17:12.547 27072-27125/com.example.projjava I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
2020-07-15 16:17:12.547 27072-27125/com.example.projjava I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2020-07-15 16:17:12.547 27072-27125/com.example.projjava I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
2020-07-15 16:17:12.547 27072-27125/com.example.projjava I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2020 08:17:13 GMT
2020-07-15 16:17:12.548 27072-27125/com.example.projjava I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"workScheduleID":"d7a8481f-02ae-458d-a220-71c4f5487540","workScheduleFromDateTime":"2020-07-07T11:52:34.483","workScheduleToDateTime":"2020-07-07T11:52:34.483","workScheduleStatus":"Not Taken","workDescriptionID":"bcf86f34-41a7-42b7-9ab4-a4c178e68fbe","branchID":"8d55ba9e-4f4b-4817-889f-8f82a2f6c065","staffID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","managerID":"b7fe0bb3-cfda-459e-8f08-178209336c2d"}
2020-07-15 16:17:12.548 27072-27125/com.example.projjava I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (403-byte body)
```

OnFailure log from retrofit2

```
2020-07-15 16:17:12.975 27072-27072/com.example.projjava D/FragmentProfile: onFailure: failed
```

Get method in jsonplaceholderapi class

```
@GET("api/WorkSchedule/{id}")
    Call<List<Schedule>> getSchedule(@Path ("id") String WorkScheduleID);
```

How I am calling the get method via this function:

```
private void getSchedules() {

        Call<List<Schedule>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().getSchedule("d7a8481f-02ae-458d-a220-71c4f5487540");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Schedule>>(){

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Schedule>> call, Response<List<Schedule>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }

                List<Schedule> schedules = response.body();
                textViewResult.setText(schedules.get(0).getWorkScheduleID());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Schedule>> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText("failed");
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+"failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out why, apparantly im not supposed to use a <List> but a  since its only one json body.